# Go Away: Wrong Chain

Tags: nodeos, error

I am really not certain what happened here, but I was trying to change my keypair in the config.ini file because I could not get it to register as a block producer. And then after restarting it I have this error:

```
["testnet.protonchain.com:9876" 95.217.107.87:9876]received go_away_message, reason = wrong chain
```

I tried to revert back to the previous key to at least get it to sync again. But now it will not do anything.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried running with `./start.sh --delete-all-blocks --genesis-json genesis.json` again thinking maybe if I just restart the sync .. does not work. Thoroughly confused, any ideas?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Someone from the telegram channel helped me find the solution. This is what worked for me -- restoring from the latest snapshot:

```
cd /opt/ProtonTestnet/protonNode
rm blocks/*
rm state/*
cd /opt/ProtonTestnet/protonNode/snapshots/
wget http://backup.cryptolions.io/ProtonTestNet/snapshots/latest-snapshot.bin
unzstd  latest-snapshot.bin
cd /opt/ProtonTestnet/protonNode
./start.sh --snapshot /opt/ProtonTestnet/protonNode/snapshots/latest-snapshot.bin
```

After I did this, I might add I was no longer getting this error while trying to register as a block producer on the testnet:

```
'{"actor":"luminaryvisn","permission":"active"}', but does not have signature -
```